# QT - modify html in QTextBrowser without reparse whole HTML

Tags: qt

I'm newbie in QT. I need display html formatted text. In Delphi (Lazarus exactly) I have IpHTML panel from TurboPowerIP library. What I like in this widget is that it parse HTML tags to the pascal objects. So I can enumarate html nodes and add new `<p></p>` by passing new object TIpNodeP.Create to the parent (e.g. BODY) node without re-set all HTML from string. This solution is very efficient for "chat dialog" applications where you need to add new part to existing html. Can I do something similar in QT? This is probably called DOM nodes. I'm looking at QTextDocument help. I see something like `QTextBlock findBlock()` but don't see how to insert new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going in the right direction.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-cursor.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextcursor.html#insertBlock

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextcursor.html#details

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext.html

Hope that helps.